# RLE Decompression Mutlithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, encoding, parallel-processing

I have an array of run length encoded binary data (Pbm image). One color Bit + 7 Bit length. How could you decode this into the original bitmap with Multithreading?
Does every thread decode it into a separate array and later on they are combined to one? Problem is, you would iterate over each value when combining the data. Is there a more efficient approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In RLE you can simply split the compressed data into chunks of approximately same length (you just need to make sure you are not splitting in the middle of some data that should stay in the same chunk) and pass to different threads to decode. Then concatenate the results.

Comment: Ommit multi-threading? This is a problem little suitable for a multi-threaded approach, though it might be doable – indeed every thread would need to extract its data into its own array, and after all of these have completed this task, *then* you could calculate the positions in the final target array every thread needs to copy its data to, which needs to be single-threaded, so only one thread active while the other ones waiting, finally the copying can then again be done in parallel.

Comment: Actually not fully true, if you enumerate your chunks of data from 1 to n and assign chunk k to thread k then actually only each thread k+1 needs to wait for its predecessor thread k to have extraction completed, and at this point both threads k and k+1 can start copying data back to the target.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try to implement that. ;)

Comment: Is this homework? Why do you even think about multithreading for this task?